# Set value of a select box

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following select-box:

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="us">America</option>
    <option value="jp">Japan</option>
    <option value="cn">China</option>
    <option value="vi">Vietnam</option>
</select>
```

By default, the value of this select-box is "us" and the displayed text is "America".
What I want to do is set the value of this select box to "jp" and set the text displayed on this select-box to "Japan" using javascript.

I can set the value to "jp" easily by setting the "selected" attribute to "true", but I can't change the text display on the select-box (It still display "America" instead of "Japan").

Are there anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Here's the [HTML way of doing this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp). If the issues still persists then check if the selectedIndex is being changed through script anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value of the select itself rather than set the options selected to true.

```
var element = document.getElementsByName('country')[0];
element.value = 'jp';
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, add `selected="selected"` based on your preference in HTML, Javascript `document.getElementsByName('country')[0].value`.

**Using HTML:**

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="us">America</option>
    <option value="jp" selected="selected" >Japan</option>
    <option value="cn">China</option>
    <option value="vi">Vietnam</option>
</select>
```

**Using javascript:**

```
  document.getElementsByName('country')[0].value = 'jp';
```

Answer (score 0):

To use JavaScript, you could use...

```
selectElement.value = "jp";
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NL44Y/).